# Does Kotlin provide any performance boosts?

Tags: java, kotlin

Does Kotlin provide any performance boosts? 
Is there any benchmarking? 
Is Kotlin faster than Java?
I found this in the Kotlin website. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/comparison-to-java.html
Talking about the language features but not performance.

Comment: Compilation time is really the only performance difference I can think of

Comment: @Tdorno I've also read (source: https://redd.it/3ddj8w) that because Kotlin inlines lambda calls, where Java creates anonymous classes, Kotlin can be marginally faster in this case. But for the most part, Kotlin is going to compile to _roughly_ the same byte code and be just as fast as Java.

Comment: There is no good way to be really faster than Java on JVM for any language, so asking that of Kotlin is fairly unreasonable.

Comment: Kotlin will have roughly the same compile and runtime speeds as Java does. Here's a good article with benchmarks of the former https://medium.com/keepsafe-engineering/kotlin-vs-java-compilation-speed-e6c174b39b5d

Comment: And no, this question is not too broad.

Comment: Well, it starts with the fact that almost each sentence is its own question. I agree that the answer addresses many aspects but still is missing certain aspects - always an indication of too broad questions.

Comment: Kotlin might get some performance boost on Android P compared to Java : https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/03/07/android-p-feature-spotlight-kotlin-apps-get-performance-boost/ , https://youtu.be/LBBqTd6uOd4

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Kotlin generates very similar bytecode to Java, so the performance of Kotlin code is in most cases the same as the performance of the equivalent Java code.

One way in which Kotlin can be faster than Java is [inline functions](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html). With inline functions, code using higher-order functions such as `filter` or `map` can be compiled to simple loop-based bytecode that doesn't create any objects or use any virtual calls (unlike Java code that uses the same type of functions).

Some benchmarks for Kotlin can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-benchmarks), [here](https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/kotlinshiddencosts-benchmarks) and [here](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1231573/FULLTEXT01.pdf).

Comment: I wonder how much of a difference Kotlin inline functions really make; the JVM/JIT is very good at inlining methods at runtime as well. If the Kotlin compiler wouldn't do the inlining, the JVM would most likely do it at runtime.

Comment: The JVM is really good at inlining simple method calls, but not so good in inlining a megamorphic call site such as the code of a `filter` function.

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/athaydes.com/renato-athaydes/posts/kotlinshiddencosts-benchmarks

Comment: I'd point out that Kotlin sometimes hides method calls as accessors of properties. So if you accessed a public field in Java and assume you do the same in Kotlin now, it's actually a method call. This might be a bit slower.
Just something that came into my mind.

Comment: These method calls will almost certainly be inlined by Hotspot, so the property access won't be any slower in practice.

Comment: According to a study by Patrik Schwermer(2018) to evaluate the performance(memory consumption, garbage collection, boxing primitives and bytecode n-grams) of Kotlin and Java on Android Runtime, 
- Kotlin is slower than Java 

Read full report here http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1231573/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: One more benchmark to link in the answer: https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/kotlin-java-performance