# Is it applicable to write a JDBC driver in Kotlin?

Tags: jdbc, kotlin, jython

Upon writing a DB-API interface, and a basic SQLAlchemy dialect for our database, I was assigned to pick up Java, and write a JDBC driver as well. I gather it'll be Level 4, with sockets against the database and such.

I know Zero Java. I intended to pick up Kotlin at some point, so I was wondering whether it'd be feasible to create a JDBC driver in Kotlin.

For example, as far as I know, Kotlin can use Java libraries. Not sure of the other way around - would any Java application be able to use a Kotlin JDBC driver, if written properly? What would be "properly" in this case? Other considerations to be noted?

Any feedback would be appreciated.

- I also considered Jython, but I'm less inclined as I suspect it'll be less fitting, though not really sure on this one as well.

Comment: I see no disadvantages of writing it in Kotlin. Yes, you can use Java from Kotlin and Kotlin from Java

Comment: Thanks! How about performance though, should I expect a speed bump?

Comment: [Kotlin is probably as fast as Java. So no, no speed reduces but don't expect too much improvements either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44081105/do-kotlin-provide-any-performance-boosts)

Comment: Doesn't Kotlin have a runtime dependency? If so, it might be better not to do this. Speaking from experience, it is better to minimize external dependencies in a JDBC driver (preferably none at all).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. If you can elaborate some more in a separate answer I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this. JDBC driver vendors need to implement certain Java `interfaces` in package `java.sql` which is totally feasible with Kotlin as much as with Java. Just do it :)

You can get started with [`Driver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html)

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Any further level of verbosity to help me pitch this to my superiors would be appreciated :)

Comment: What would they want to hear?

Comment: I was aiming at better maintainability, more leisurable interaction and future profit from adding Kotlin to our stack

Comment: I think to greatest argument pro Kotlin is "productivity". See, Java is a great language but Kotlin picks it up and makes it so much easier and better. Many tasks (singleton, data classes, delegation, etc.) are implemented in the language which can easily be applied with simple keywords rather than with lots of boilerplate as in Java. There are many examples for that. And of course, this in turn makes way more fun, when you don't have to repeat yourself over and over. Personally, other reasons for Kotlin: extensions, more functional, coroutines, industry experts behind it (JetBrains), FUN :)

Comment: How about the runtime dependency issue @MarkRotteveel pointed out?